# OOD - Best way to pass config to an external class

Tags: java, oop

In my main method I need to execute a system command. I'm creating an external class to execute the command to keep my main method and app class clean. I'm not sure if the best or cleanest approach would be to do the setup for the command in the main method, or just pass the class the configuration reader and let it pull the necessary things it needs.

Would it make my app more tightly coupled or not follow a good design practice if I just pass the external configuration reader to my SystemCommand class?

Ex - approach one to setup from the main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

String[] command = { 
    config.getString("program"),
    config.getString("audit.script.name"),
    config.getString("audit.script.config")
    };
String workingDir = config.getString("audit.directory");
SystemCommand runAudit = new SystemCommand(command, workingDir);
runAudit.start();
}
```

Or alternatively, I can keep the main method simpler by passing a reference to the config and letting the class pull what it needs from there. It seems this approach is still conceptually simple:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
SystemCommand runAudit = new SystemCommand(config);
runAudit.start();
}
```

There's also a matter of configuring where output and logging is specified, but I haven't thought that through yet.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your `main()` method simple. Your `main()` method should not have knowledge about the inner details of other classes in the program. This is because it is an entry point and generally entry points should concern themselves with minimalistic initialization and any other house-keeping tasks. The best way to solve your use case would be :

Create a class `SystemCommandFactory` which would take in a `Config` instance as a constructor parameter I assume below that `SystemCommand` is an interface that could have multiple implementations:

```
public class SystemCommandFactory
{
     private final Config config;

     public SystemCommandFactory(Config config)
     {
        this.config = config;
     }

    //assume we have a ping system command
    public SystemCommand getPingCommand()
    {
        //build system command
        SystemCommand command1 = buildSystemCommand(); 
        return command;
    }

    //assume we have a copy system command
    public SystemCommand getCopyCommand()
    {
        //build system command
        SystemCommand command2 = buildSystemCommand(); 
        return command;
    }
}
```

Now your main method would be as simple as :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   SystemCommandFactory factory = new SystemCommandFactory(new Config());

   //execute command 1
   factory.getPingCommand().execute();
   //execute command 2
   factory.getCopyCommand().execute();
}
```

This way you can see that `main()` method is simple clean and this design is definitely extensible. Adding a new command say `MoveCommand` is as simple as :

1. Create a implementation of the `SystemCommand` interface for the new
   command.
2. Expose a new method within the factory to get this new `MoveCommand`
3. In `main()` call this new factory method to get the new command and
   call execute within it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems cleaner.